# UnsatisfiedLinkError, Cocos2D-x app crash on startup

Tags: android-ndk, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

My Cocos2D-x app is working only on android 22+ and crash in lower platforms throwing an exception java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

**App config:**

- Target SDK version 22 (Android Lollipop).
- Min SDK is 14.
- NDK r10c with eclipse.

Comment: Cocos2dx is for game ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

Very useful answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27093163/3547788

**Old solution:**
Possible fix by changing the ndkr10 to ndkr9 then the app will work for all android versions, For NDK10:

- changing the target & min sdk at the manifest to 14
- add APP_PLATFORM := android-14 to application.mk
- clean and build.

Answer (score 0):

Well you decide on the minimum version of Android to support and your game is then expected to run on all versions from that version to the latest version.

You cannot, for example, decide to support 2.3, 4.0.4 and 5.0.1, but not 4.4.2 and 5.0.

See `<uses-sdk>` [reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).