# How do you view the raw Gradle build log for the NDK in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, gradle-experimental

When using the [Gradle experimental plugin](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) with Android studio to build an NDK library, how do you see the low-level build log i.e. the compiler invocations for each file with all the arguments etc...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the experimental plugin the build log is in the gradle log file. On my Mac, that is in ~/Library/Logs/Android1.3/idea.log

You can run gradle with --debug or --info options for more verbose output. Running from the command line also produces more verbose output than in the IDE.

There is a lot of additional information in build/tmp/{buildstep} that is the output of the tools. Each build step will have a "options.txt" and "output.txt" file in it that shows the command options sent to the tool and the output of the tool respectively.

Comment: What if build/tmp/{buildstep} is empty?